# How can use $add, $subtract in pymongo?

Tags: python, database, nosql, pymongo

What is the reason for my code error?

I expect it to return 200, but I'm wrong

**TypeError : update_one() missing 1 required positional argument, 'update'**

Please give an example of how to use $add and $subtract in pymongo , thanks

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClinet("localhost", 27017)
db= client.db.orders
db.insert_one({"val":100})
db.update_one({"val":{"$add":100}})
```

Comment: if you're updating you need to pass in a filter and a json object to actually update it with

Answer (score 1):

You must tell MongoDB which document to update with the first parameter; also to add (or subtract) use the [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
coll=client.db.orders
coll.insert_one({"val":100})
coll.update_one({"val":100}, {"$inc": {"val":100}})
```